# My Xbox logged me in as someone else - how can I fix this?

Tags: xbox-one, kinect

Today, while already logged in as myself, my Xbox One suddenly seemed to recognize someone else in the room and automatically logged them in. However, the other person was nowhere near the room when this happened.

This hasn't interfered with my own experience yet, as I'm still being treated as the current and primary user. Regardless, I'd like to know how to prevent this from occurring in the future.

What can cause a false-positive recognition and login, and how can I prevent it without disabling auto-login features?

---

UPDATE:

After several re-calibrations, the system is still doing this occasionally. Typically, I don't have a problem being recognized myself. But the system still seems to spot the other person in the room when they're not.

I looked around the room to double-check things, and there's not even a picture of the person in view of Kinect. One time, shortly after the false-positive login, I switched over to the Kinect settings screen and the user identifier was hovering over my right shoulder.

I was being properly identified, but something over my shoulder (nothing there but the couch and wall) was being recognized as the other person. If I moved around, my tag followed me but the other tag moved asynchronously. I couldn't pin down what, exactly, the system was seeing there. I haven't done any re-testing since though, to see if it's the same spot every time or just some random whatever.

Also, due to other unrelated issues, the system I was using when I originally posted this question has been replaced with a new console. I'm still having this problem with the new system.

Comment: Maybe the Kinect picked up a ghost.... wooooOOOOOooooo

Comment: Do they use Smartglass?

Comment: @Brok3n They do, but certainly weren't at the moment. Also, the system is set to only allow SmartGlass control for users logged into it. While troubleshooting a SmartGlass issue awhile ago, I discovered that meant it will only allow control for users *currently* logged in - i.e.: if someone's not already logged in, SmartGlass won't get them on.

Answer (score 2):

Each profile can be set to use Kinect login separately. So if you only want you to be automatically logged in you can set that as such by going to settings->sign, security, and passkey->kinect sign in.

You can also do that method to calibrate the Kinect so it recognizes you or the "distracting" user better. Unless you are twins... this method should work.

Comment: How do I do the calibration? I've been through the process before, and I don't remember there being a calibration option.

Comment: Just redoing it will recalibrate it. Sometimes people's appearances change (haircut, shave, etc) and Kinect needs to know your new look. When Kinect asks "is this you?" that's what you need to pay attention.

Comment: I literally just set the system up two days ago, and there's really not all that much similarity between my face and the other user's. I'll give the reset a try and see if the problem recurs though.

Comment: My thought on why the calibration might help is that it might have a really fuzzy internal idea of what the other user looks like so you get more false positives. Redoing that user might get an internal representation of them less prone to these errors. I don't really know how it all works for sure though so this thought might be pure rubbish. :)